# How to deal with long asynchronous stored procedure called from spring server?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, transactions, mybatis

I use `spring-boot`, `mybatis` and I execute an asynchronous stored procedure. It is asynchronous because it is a procedure from `SSIS` package (catalog schema) - these procedures are asynchronous by default.

The problem is that before executing the stored procedure, I modify some value in the database. Due to the fact that it is asynchronous, annotation `@Transactional` doesn't help me.

The thing that I am worried about is failure of executing this package (SSIS catalog - `start_execution`). It this case I should revert the previous value in database (one value, but it doesnt matter here). 
However, `@Transactional` can't help me because as you know `spring` think that the procedure finished successfully and it accepts the transaction.

How to deal with this problem - I mean rollback in case of failure of execution of a ssis package ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this post](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/davide_mauri/archive/2011/11/24/execute-a-ssis-package-in-sync-or-async-mode-from-sql-server-2012.aspx), you can run a SSIS prodecure synchronously using the right parameter:

*[...]
You have to be sure that you add the “SYNCHRONIZED” parameter to the package execution. Before the start_execution procedure:*

`exec [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] @execution_id,  @object_type=50, @parameter_name=N'SYNCHRONIZED', @parameter_value=1`

At this point, you should be able to wait for the completion of the procedure as usual and handle rollback normally.